# Uso de .Random en python

Tags: python

Espero que tengan un excelente dia muchachos
Lo que deseo hacer es que cada vez que se recurra a la variable se genere un numero diferente, pero con la variable que estoy usando se genera uno, pero sigue siendo constante, lo que deseo es que este intervalo cambie cada vez que sea requerido por el aplicativo. deseo que la variable machine fluctue entre 1 y 3 y que siempre que se requiera sea diferente. Gracias soy principiante y ando aprendiendo

ejemplo de mi codigo:

```py
user_choice = input("Please enter your choice ")
machine = random.randint(1,3)
print(str(dictionary[user_choice.lower()]))

while vida != 0:
    if int(dictionary[user_choice.strip()]) == machine:
        print("You are very lucky today")
        print("Its a tie")
        user_choice = input("Please enter your choice")
    else:
        vida -= 1
        print("Perdiste una vida" + str(vida))
        user_choice = input("Please enter your choice")
```

Comment: podrías hacerlo usando un diccionario `dic = {"machine": lambda: random.randint(1,3)}` y cada vez que lo uses `dic["machine"]()` tendrá un valor distinto

Comment: Gracias bro! Lo intente y funciono! :D

Comment: hice una respuesta con una forma más simplificada. Se me ocurrió luego del comentario

Comment: Tenes una respuesta.. y esta ok.. pero te hago una pregunta.. cual es tu pregunta??? si cada vez que llamas a random.randint(1,3) te devuelve un nuevo numero aleatorio, cual es tu duda??? cuando queres que se cree un nuevo numero????

Comment: Quiero que se cree un nuevo numero al volver a pedirle al usuario un nuevo numero, para comparar, por que entonces pedia el numero pero el numero de la maquina seguia siendo el mismo y no modificaba

Comment: random.randint(1,3) debe ir adentro del bucle while para que genere un nuevo valor cada vez que se le pida la entrada al usuario porque si no esta adentro solo generará un único valor constante

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luego de escribir el comentario me di cuenta que se podía simplificar. Si bien puedes hacerlo usando diccionarios donde la clave sea el nombre de la variable y el valor sea una función lambda y la función lambda retornará el valor creado por `random`, por lo que cada vez que se acceda a tal índice se ejecutará la función:

```py
dic = {"machine": lambda: random.randint(1,3)}

#hacemos pruebas
print(dic["machine"]())
print(dic["machine"]())
print(dic["machine"]())
print(dic["machine"]())
```

Pero... eso se puede simplificar tan solo creando la función lambda y asignarselo a una variable:

```py
#creamos una función lambda sin parametros
machine = lambda: random.randint(1,3)

#probamos
print(machine())
print(machine())
print(machine())
print(machine())
```

Para este caso de igual forma usamos los paréntesis ya que estamos invocando a una función, sería lo mismo que hacer

```py
def machine():
    return random.randint(1,3)
```

Pero en una sola línea!

Comment: O sea.. el problema era que no estaba volviendo a llamar a random cada vez que queria un nuevo numero??? porque esta respuesta es exactamente lo mismo que esta en la pregunta....

Comment: en la pregunta solo se llama a random una sola vez :/

Comment: Por eso.. el problema es que no llamaba a random nunca mas.. o sea... todo lo que esta aca no contesta la duda, que es: "hay que volver a llamar a random si queres otro numero"....

Comment: si responde a la pregunta, para eso creo la función lambda `machine` y recuerda que para evitar debates extensos está el chat (sus notificaciones son muy lentas)

Comment: Es que lo que ocurria es que como por ejemplo tirar los datos y comparar tu resultado con el de la maquina, entonces cada vez que respondes un numero la maquina genera un numero aleatorio, lo que ocurria es que generaba uno aleatorio y cuando se ejecutaba la funcion seguia siendo el mismo numero :D Gracias muchachos